# RPM merging and upgrading

Tags: rpm

I have 2 rpms rpm-abc , rpm-xyz . rpm-xyz is dependent on rpm-abc and depdendency is rpm-xyz can't be installed if there is no rpm-abc.

rpm-abc creates a directory abc in my system and rpm-xyz creates a directory xyz.

Now we merged rpm-xyz to rpm-abc.

Now i am having below issue.
On my system i have installed rpm-abc and rpm-xyz.
Now i wanted to update it to merged rpm-abc.
so I have done it through rpm -Uvh rpm-abc. This is succesfull.
But when i do rpm -aq|grep rpm-xyz it shows rpm-xyz is still on system.

So in spec file of rpm-abc i have added below entry.

Obsoletes: rpm-xyz.

As per my understanding when we upgrade the rpm-abc rpm-xyz get's unistalled.
Now i am having different issue with this.
As said earlier abc and xyz directories when i have installed rpm-abc and rpm-xyz directories respectively.

Now when i have done rpm -Uvh rpm-abc it uninstalls the rpm-xyz
As part of uninstallation it is also removing xyz directory which should not happen.

Now i am searching for a way that when i do rpm -Uvh rpm-abc it should uninstall rpm-xyz by skipping the removal of directory xyz. Looking for some help here mates?

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the line:

```
%files
%dir xyz
```

from rpm-xyz to rpm-abc? That should do it.

BTW There is guidelines how to do the merging more precisely: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#renaming-or-replacing-existing-packages